# Casperjs not working with javascript app page

Tags: backbone.js, phantomjs, casperjs

I've been digging and the internet for a solution to this but can't find one.  I'm trying to use CasperJS to load and submit this [form here](https://dashboard.chartboost.com/session/login).

But when I run my code and have it take a screenshot of the loaded page it is a grey page (so the background of that page) with no login form (either in the capture or if I search for it in the code).

The page does appear to be a backbone.js driven app from the included scripts.

Here's the code I've been using:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    viewportSize: {width: 1300, height: 700},
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug",
    pageSettings: {
        localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled: true,
        userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36",
    },
});


casper.start('https://dashboard.chartboost.com/session/login', function() {
    this.wait(20000,function(){
        this.capture('revenue.png',{
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            width: 1300,
            height: 700
        });
    });
});


casper.then(function() {
    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
});

casper.run();
```

I've tried several different options and settings without any luck.  Should CasperJS work in this situation or am I trying to use it for something it wasn't meant to be used for?

Any info or ideas would be awesome.

Edit 1:  Added User Agent being used for testing.

Edit 2: After adding the error printing code I get the following error:

```
Error:    TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.start.bind(this)')
file:     https://assets.chartboost.com/scripts/compiled.js
line:     2
```

I should also note that I am running version 1.1-beta-3

Comment: The code looks fine, try adding a user agent, to make sure they are not sniffing you as a bot.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes Funny enough I actually had a user agent in my test code but decided to strip it before posting the code here.  I'll add it back in.

Comment: Try catching js error like here: https://coderwall.com/p/uzaaaw Probably the site is using things that phantomjs doesn't support

Comment: @ChrisHawkes No it did not work.  It didn't appear to make any difference.

Comment: @JakubKania Ah, there is an error being thrown, see my edit.

Comment: is that the whole code what exactly is on line 2? is this a viewport issue?

Comment: @ChrisHawkes After doing some digging I guess PhantomJS doesn't support the .bind() function (using an older JavaScript engine).  But CasperJS has a polyfill for this (in the core bootstrap.js file), but it doesn't seem to be working like it should.   Line 2 of the `compiled.js` file is where it the .bind() function is trying to be run and where CasperJS/PhantomJS is coughing.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? I think I may be seeing the same thing. I used CasperBox on a live site that is using Backbone and received: Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.setWindowDimensions.bind(this,this.$container)')

Comment: There wasn't ever really a solution.  The problem is PhantomJS doesn't have JS bind() built into it.  CasperJS comes with a polyfill for it (and I verified it was there) but for some reason I could never get it to work.  So I eventually just gave up.